# In a big, wide html bootstrap table, how do i control the horizontal scrolling?

Tags: css, laravel, bootstrap-5

I'm working on Laravel project and I have this table and it is overflowed from the right side, I tried some available methods for horizontal scroll but they just don't work with me...I can control the width of the card behind the table but the table does not changed

Anyone knows how to overcome this horizontal scroll matter would be highly appreciate it!
Here is a screenshot of the overflowed part of the table:
[overflowed table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFWjE.png)

````
`
```
<x-app-layout>

</x-app-layout>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <style>
        a {
            text-underline-offset: 5px;
        }

        table-bordered {
            max-width: 420;
        }
        .card-body,
        .card {
            max-width: 1240px;
        }
        .table-width {
            max-width: 120px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-scroller">
        <div class="main-panel">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body"> <a style="float: right; width: 20%;" class="nav-link btn btn-success create-new-button" id="createbuttonDropdown" href="{{url('/addLecturer')}}">+ Add New lecturer</a>
                        <h4 class="card-title">Columns Table</h4>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row text-center">
                            <table class="table table-bordered" class="table-width">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr align="center">
                                        <td>clo1</td>
                                        <td>clo2</td>
                                        <td>clo3</td>
                                        <td>clo4</td>
                                        <td>clo5</td>
                                        <td>clo6</td>
                                        <td>clo7</td>
                                        <td>clo8</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach ($x as $data)
                                    <tr align="center">
                                        <td>{{$data['clo1]}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$data['clo2']}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$data['clo3']}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$data['clo4']}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$data['clo5']}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$data['clo6']}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$data['clo7']}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
````

Comment: Step 1: `<table class="table table-bordered" class="table-width">` do not add `class` two times, just paste your custom class after the original bootstrap classes. Step 2: bootstrap has a class called `table-responsive` add that to your table classes and see if the scrolling will start to happen

Comment: take a look at bootstap documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/#always-responsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add class `table-responsive` to the `div` holding your table

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/#always-responsive